# Flutter: Upon OnTap() from Page A navigate to Page B and perform a particular function, which is declared at Page B

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

Sorry in advance, I'm new to flutter and dart language thus I'm not really familiar with the usage of it.

Currently, I have a `ListTile` from `Page A`, which contains the information (latitude and longitude), and upon clicking on any of the items from `ListTile`, it is supposed to pass the information of that particular item to `Page B` and perform a function (zoom in on Google Map based on the passed latitude and longitude from `Page A`) which is declared at `Page B`.

I understand that to go from one page to another page, we can make use of the `Navigator` but I still could not figure out how to call the function and pass the information. Thus, I hope that I will be able to get some guidance or assistance in regard to it.

This is the function that I try to call in `Page B`:

```
_goToLocation(Information information) {
    mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(
            double.parse(infomration.latitude),
            double.parse(information.longitude),
          ),
          zoom: 18.0,
        ),
      ),
    );   }
```

I manage to go to `Page B` to `Page A` using the below codes, which will be execute upon clicking on any of the items from `ListTile` (via `onTap()`) but I am unsure how do I call the function in `Page B` to run making use of this code. I was wondering if I am able to call the function using the below codes?

```
void navigationToExplore(Information information) async {
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Explore();
    }));
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass to you data from Screen A to Screen B

```
void navigationToExplore(Information information) async {
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Explore(
          lat : latitude,
          long : longitude,
      );
    }));
  }
```

Now your Screen B :-

```
class Explore extends StatefulWidget {
  final double lat;
  final double long;

  Explore({this.lat, this.long});

  @override
  _Explore createState() => _Explore();
}

class _Explore extends State<Explore> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _googleMapCompleter = Completer();

  updateCameraPosition(){
    LatLng userCoordinates = LatLng(widget.jobData.lat, widget.jobData.long);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
      target: userCoordinates,
      zoom: 15,
    );
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _googleMapCompleter.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     updateCameraPosition();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0, 0)),
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          _controller = controller;
          _googleMapCompleter.complete(_controller);
        },
        // this wont allow screen scrolling from google maps
        gestureRecognizers: Set()
          ..add(
              Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())),
      )
    );
  }
}
```